# CSS3 floated element won't clear

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a navigation bar for a website and I need it, of course, to be centered and list items floated. My problem is that the images under the navigation bar keep floating along with it and I used clear:both property, so I'm confused. HTML code goes like this:

```
<body>

<div id="header">
  <img src="img/headerImg.jpg" alt="Header image" id ="headerImg" />

  <div id = "nav">
    <ul>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href = "index.html">Početna</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href = "">Dizajn</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href = "">Web programiranje</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href = "">Ostale usluge</a></li>
  <li class="menuItem"><a href = "">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
  </div> <!--close nav-->

</div> <!--close header-->

<div id="indexContent">

  <div class="indexContentItem">
    <img src="img/indexDes.jpg" alt="Dizajn" class="indexContentImg"/>
    <p><a href="">Dizajn</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="indexContentItem">
    <img src="img/indexProg.jpg" alt="Web programiranje" class="indexContentImg"/>
    <p><a href="">Web programiranje</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="indexContentItem">
    <img src="img/indexRest.png" alt="Ostale usluge" class="indexContentImg"/>
    <p><a href="">Ostale usluge</a></p>
  </div>

</div> <!--close indexContent-->
```

And CSS is:

```
#nav{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
}

#nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12em;
    float: left;
}

#nav ul{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav a{
    display: block;
}

.indexContentItem{
    float: left;
}

.indexContentItem img{
    display: block;
    height: 15.625em;
    width: auto;
}

.indexContentItem p{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Of course, I pasted only the relevant parts and it is a mockup version as it is still under construction, but this screenshot should give you the idea of what is going on:

[image: screenshot:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) should solve your problem.

```
#nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Could I please bother you to explain what does :after pseudo-class do? I looked on the web, but it's pretty confusing and contradictory.

Comment: The :after pseudo-element allows you to insert content after an element. Here's an  [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwEwKM). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::after) also has some pretty good examples if you want to check them out.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

```
#nav{
width: 90%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
clear: both;
position: absolute;
}
```

the `position` attribute has different options, this may help:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp